# how to fix duplicate entry error in Laravel 5.7?

Tags: laravel-5, controller

I am using a user verification system in email with Laravel 5.7 this is working fine. but when I tried to enter the same email with verification form it is generating following massages.

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'mymail@gmail.com' for key 'users_email_unique' (SQL: insert into `users` (`email`, `name`, `address`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (mymail@gmail.com, Banda, Sysney, 2019-05-31 11:32:36, 2019-05-31 11:32:36))

my UserController is like this,

```
protected function store(Request $request)
{

    $user = new User;

    $user->email = $request->input('email');
    $user->name = $request->input('name');
    $user->address = $request->input('address');

    $user->save();

    $verifyUser = VerifyUser::create([
        'user_id' => $user->id,
        'token' => str_random(40)
    ]);
}
```

how can fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

As it seems and also very common, your `users` table seems to have a UNIQUE INDEX on `email` so if you try to create an entry with an email which already exists, it is normal to get this error.

I am not sure what exactly you want to do from your question context but I believe if you just want to create a VerifyUser entry, you could use `updateOrCreate()` for User and go on with VerifyUser logic like so:

```
protected function store(Request $request)
{
    $email = $request->input('email');
    $name = $request->input('name');
    $address = $request->input('address');

    $user = User::updateOrCreate(['email' => $email], ['name' => $name, 'address' => $address]);

    $verifyUser = VerifyUser::create([
        'user_id' => $user->id,
        'token' => str_random(40)
    ]);
}
```

*I hope it helps*

Comment: actually, I do not want to update my current email address. I need to add an existing email address as a new table row to the data table.

Comment: Then just remove the UNIQUE index from your `email` column of `users` table